# Subscriptions or Push Notifications?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, graphql

I am building an App with react-native as I am fairly new to native development I want to get more clarification on what is the best option for me?

As my App depends on real-time communication, is it the best option to use `graph-ql subscriptions` plus `push notifications` or using just `graph-ql subscriptions` will be fine or maybe I should just use `push notifications` only?

Any kind of help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you give a specific example you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Bojke !! Consider my as a chatting App and we all know real-time communication is one of the key features, so I'm wondering whether to use only GraphQL subscription for my real-time communication or just use push notifications or combine the two to archive a greater user experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the message in background you will definitely need push-notification, but nothing will guarantee that the notification will be received in real-time.
I would suggest you to use both.
In foreground you need to ensure everything happens immediately, subscriptions do their job here.
You should send a push notification and trigger the subscription on every message.
Also this way you can easily implement typing feature, online/offline status etc...

Comment: Thanks, @Bojke for your answer, so in the foreground, I will just ignore the data received from push notifications and use the subscription instead?

Comment: Exactly. At least that's what I would do.